# Return data when is none in one of the clause

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm

I have a query which every time must return me some data, but it doesn't because my clause `andWhere` causes me to return an empty list from my query when it is not true,

my code:

```
const user = await this.conn.getRepository(User).createQueryBuilder("user")
  .where(`user.id = ${userID}`)
  .letJoin('user.orders', 'orders')
  .andWhere('orders.dateService BETWEEN ${start} AND ${end}')
  .addSelect("user.firstName", "firstName")
  .addSelect("user.lastName", "lastName")
  .getRawMany((;
```

this query return me `empty []` because in my clause `.andWhere('orders.dateService BETWEEN ${start} AND ${end}')`  I find none order...

can someone tell me how to return my `firstName` and `lastName` even when the above clause return me `none`?

thanks for any help

Comment: What is `letJoin`? Is this actually `leftJoin` in your code? Because `leftJoin` should have exactly that behaviour you want.

Comment: yes this is `leftJoin`, can you show how do it?

Answer (score 1):

In your query the condition `orders.dateService BETWEEN ${start} AND ${end}` is actually responsible that you don't have any results. Because if there are no orders for the userid, this condition is always false, because `orders.dateService` is NULL.

So you will have to add an additional condition, where you allow `orders.dateService` to be NULL.

```js
const user = await this.conn.getRepository(User).createQueryBuilder("user")
  .where(`user.id = ${userID}`)
  .leftJoin('user.orders', 'orders')
  .andWhere(new Brackets(qb => {
        qb.where('orders.dateService BETWEEN ${start} AND ${end}')
          .orWhere('orders.dateService IS NULL')
    }))
  .addSelect("user.firstName", "firstName")
  .addSelect("user.lastName", "lastName")
```

This will create (more or less) the following SQL query

```sql
SELECT user.firstname as firstName, user.lastName as lastName
FROM user LEFT JOIN orders ON user.id = orders.user
WHERE user.id = ${USERID} AND
  (orders.dateService BETWEEN ${start} AND ${end} OR orders.dateService IS NULL)
```